# Count possible decodings of a given digit sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose we have a string of binary values in which some portions may correspond to specific letters, for example:

```
A = 0
B = 10
C = 001
D = 010
E = 001
```

For example, if we assume the string "001010", we can have 6 different possibilities:

```
AABB
ADB
CAB
CD
EAB
ED
```

I have to extract the exact number of combinations.
I'm trying to solve the problem conceptually by a dynamic programming point of view but I have difficulty in the formulation of subproblems and in the composition of the corresponding matrix.
I appreciate any indications of the correct algorithm formulation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little rusty at dynamic programming, but isn't this the wrong situation for it? dynamic programming is targeted toward getting an optimal result, whereas here you have multiple results. also I don't think you can use a matrix because A, B, C ... are different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can formulate a DP whereby `f(i) = sum( f(i - j) * count(matches_j) ), for all matches of length j ending at index i`, which, depending on the input, you might also speed up by creating a custom trie for the dictionary so you would only check relevant matches (e.g., A followed by B followed by D). To take your example:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 1 * f(0) = 1
f(2) = 2
f(3) = 1 * f(2) + 1 * f(1) + 1 * f(0) = 4
f(4) = 0
f(5) = 1 * f(4) + 1 * f(3) + 1 * f(2) = 6
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your solution. I tried to build a matrix in which the rows are the subproblems (the prefixes of length i) and columns are the length of the each combination to be tested (j = 1, 2, 3); but, if this is a right way, I can't understand how to fill each cell [i,j] in accordance with your formulation.

Comment: @JohnMòf Thank you for your comment. No, my suggestion is for a one-dimentional DP. I used `j` as a convenience to indicate grouping of the dictionary by length - in your example this would be `[[A],[B],[C,D,E]`. For each `i` in the DP array, you would follow my formula. The sequence of `j`s is simply the lengths of the current dictionary word/s you are trying to match.

Comment: @JohnMòf For example, at index `0`, you can only match `A` (`j = 1`); while at index `3` you can match `A`,`B`,`D` (`j = 1 then 2 then 3`). (I edited the example in my answer after noticing some mistakes; they should be fixed now.)

Comment: Now I understand! It is an optimal solution with linear complexity, congratulations! The only thing I don't understand (from a theoretical point of view) is: in the formula `f(i - j) * count(matches_j)` why to use the multiplication operation, rather than the sum? On each step you reuse the previously computed subproblem; in my head I have to sum the previous solution.

Comment: @JohnMòf I think the complexity is `O(n * k)` where `k` is the number of dictionary words, but `k` is also dependent on the length of the dictionary words. One would assume that a dictionary only has one match per `j`, in which case you would simply write `f(i - j) if match_j matches, else 0` but your dictionary seems to have multiple matches for the same substring (e.g. C and E match the same code). In that case you have to multiply since you could combine any one of those with the possibilities earlier in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple recursive procedure: try to match every pattern to the beginning of the string; if there is a match, repeat recursively with the remainder of the string. When the string is empty, you have found a decoding.

```
Patterns= ["0", "10", "001", "010", "001"]
Letters= "ABCDE"

def Decode(In, Out):
    global Patterns

    if len(In) == 0:
        print Out
    else:
        for i in range(len(Patterns)):
            if In[:len(Patterns[i])] == Patterns[i]:
                Decode(In[len(Patterns[i]):], Out + Letters[i])

Decode("001010", "")

AABB
ADB
CAB
CD
EAB
ED
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution, but it has nothing to do with the dynamic programming, isn't it? A pure recursive solution is not likely to solve the same problem more than once? And from a complexity point of view .. ?

Comment: @JohnMòf: hem, you have no objective function, and you want to be exhaustive. I am not sure there is any room for dynamic programming here.

Comment: You are right. Thanks again for your help. Your code works fine, It will help me to understand the optimal solution.

Comment: If you memoize the results, or if you compute them bottom up, then this turns into a textbook DP example.

Comment: @templatetypedef: "If you memoize the results" can you elaborate ? What exactly will you memoize ?

Comment: The goal is to count the number of matches rather than to report them, so you could modify the function to have it returns the number of matches starting at a given index. At that point, it makes a lot of sense to memoize the results because you'll potentially have a lot of overlapping calls.

Comment: @templatetypedef: that doesn't answer the question: what will you memoize ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, sorry. You'd memoize the return value of the modified version of the function (that is, you'd memoize the number of ways of decoding each suffix of the string.)

Comment: @templatetypedef: I don't see how this can help. The suffixes have different lengths so the solutions for a given prefix length aren't directly reusable for other lengths and you'll have to try partial matches. This amounts to enlarging the pattern set, and try more matches on the suffix under study. My bet is that this will just slow down the global process. The longer the memoized patterns will be, the less likely they will be later met again.

Answer (score 1):

When solving DP problems, it often helps to think about a recursive solution first, then thinking about converting it to a DP solution.

A nice recursive insight here is that if you have a nonempty string of digits, any way of decoding it will start with some single character. You could therefore count the number of ways to decode the string by trying each character, seeing if it matches at the beginning and, if so, counting up how many ways there are to decode the rest of the string.

The reason this turns into a nice DP problem is that when you pull off a single character you're left with a shorter string of digits that's always a suffix of the original string. So imagine that you made a table storing, for each suffix of the original string, how many ways there were to decode that string. If you fill that matrix in from the right to the left using the above insight, you'd ultimately end up getting the final answer by reading off the entry corresponding to the entire string.

See if you can find a way to turn this into a concrete algorithm and to then go and code it up. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to focus the problem with your point of view: I've to begin with a suffix of one character, then I consider a suffix of two characters, and so on .. ? But when I add a letter to the prefix, how can I avoid calculate everything again?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "add a letter to the prefix?"

Comment: Suppose the following string "0010". I consider each prefix: 0, 00, 001, 0010. When I consider the last (0010, the entire string) I have to sum the number of combinations obtainable with the suffix string 001 with the number of combinations can be obtained by adding the last character. Is it right?

Comment: Not quite. You'd try to split the string as 0|010, 00|10, 001|0, and 0010|. You'd use recursion/DP to determine the number of ways of splitting the string on the right of the bar (the suffix) and then add all the results together. Does that make sense?